# Creating a universal binary using Intel compiler

Tags: macos, intel, compiler-warnings, intel-composer

In MacOSX, gcc command line accepts multiarchitecture options:

```
gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 etc.
```

... and creates a universal binary by compiling and linking for both archs and running lipo for gluing them together.

However using this command line with Intel, produces a compiler warning:

```
command line warning #10121: overriding '-arch i386' with '-arch x86_64'
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a compiler limitation?
I couldn't find anything about it in the Intel developer zone.

Comment: Pretty sure its a limitation. The fat-binary magic is done by lipo anyway. Just compile it twice and glue it together with lipo. The Apple compiler isn't doing things much differently.